# Using IAuthorizationFilter with Ninject and EF gives DbContext has been disposed error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I'm trying to use my UnitOfWork inside an implementation of `IAuthorizationFilter`, but after I navigate between a few pages I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

**FilterConfig.cs**

```
filters.Add(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(PermissionFilter)));
```

**NinjectMappings.cs**

```
public class NinjectMappings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

**PermissionFilter.cs**

```
public class PermissionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public PermissionFilter(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

I was able to get around this with:

```
// NinjectMappings
Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
    .ToMethod(m => GetUnitOfWork())
    .WhenInjectedExactlyInto(typeof(PermissionFilter));

private IUnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork()
{
    return new UnitOfWork(new MyContext());
}
```

The problem now is that `GetUnitOfWork` is only called once, at app start. I tried alternating between `InTransientScope` and `InRequestScope` to no avail. So updates to the database are not retrieved, instead my UnitOfWork always returns the same data.

I have read quite a few questions dealing with `DbContext has been disposed` but none of them were implementing an `IAuthorizationFilter`.

What is the best way to solve this? I'd like to avoid `new` or `using()` inside the filter or using the Service Locator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that your MyContext is instantiated in the scope of a request and is disposed at the end of the request.

To solve this avoiding `new()`, `using`, or ServiceLocator pattern, you may rely on a dedicated `IFilterProvider`

```
public class PermissionFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly Func<PermissionFilter> _permissionFilterFactory = null;

    public PermissionFilterProvider(Func<PermissionFilter> filterFactory)
    {
        _permissionFilterFactory = filterFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = new List<Filter>(); 

        // instantiate PermissionFilter action filter  
        filters.Add(new Filter(_permissionFilterFactory(), FilterScope.Action, 0));
        return filters;
    }
}
```

Your bindings would then be :

```
public class NinjectMappings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
        Bind<IFilterProvider>().To<PermissionFilterProvider>();
        Bind<PermissionFilter>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

Note that you will need an Ninject Factory extension like [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/) to achieve the `Func<PermissionFilter>` factory pattern in `PermissionFilterProvider` constructor.

Also, I am not sure of the scope of your `IUnitOfWork`. Shouldn't it be the same as your `MyContext` ?

Comment: I tried your approach but it didn't solve the problem, I still get `DbContext has been disposed`. I tried `IUnitOfWork` with the same scope as `MyContext` (`InRequestScope`) in both my code and yours, same results.

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio I guess this problem comes from the MyContext being explicitly disposed during the request lifetime, not from Ninject. You should put a breakpoint in your MyContext Dispose method, to see the stack where it is called before the Exception is triggered

Comment: I have added `public new void Dispose()` to MyContext and put a break point on it to see if it's ever called, but it never is. It doesn't seem like it's being disposed during the request lifetime, because I can navigate the site for a while, and make a few requests from different pages. After a small pause (30 seconds), the error comes up. There may be some kind of "garbage collection" that is triggered on this pause.